# fit div width to content and not to parent

Tags: css, inheritance, nowrap

I want to make a label for a button that I have. My problem is that the label is wider then the button. I currently have it done like this (simple example):

```html
<div class="parent_container_the_icon">
    <div class="label">
        This is the label text
    </div>
<div>
```

The CSS:

```css
.parent_container_the_icon {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}

.label {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

What I want is for the label to take the width of the label text itself without wrapping the text. At the moment it doesn't wrap the text, but I get an overflow of the text in the label box as that box only takes the maximum width of the container.

How can I force the label `div` to fit the size of the text and not inherit the width of the parent?

Comment: You don't need display: block; on the div as they are by default a block level element. Also, when you add positioning to an element, it also makes it block level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you had exactly what you wanted. Perhaps check in another browser?

This is your code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QkZa4/)

Comment: This indeed worked. Sometimes you forget about the logical things. Thanks Akahadaka

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
 <div class="parent_container_the_icon">
      <div class="label">
           This it the label text
      </div>
 <div>​
```

CSS:

```
.parent_container_the_icon {
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 50px; /*<== changed width to min-width*/
    float: left;
}

.label {
    /*removed position:absolute*/
    display: block;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mythril, with a min-width it is going to push the parent container out of position. What I want is an overflow in the parent container but I want the label to push itself outside of the container based on the width of the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `white-space: nowrap;` property in a parent class and `width: 100%;` in a child.

I hope you find this useful.